# python: time complexity of a[:10]=[1,2,3]

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

A is big: `len(a)=10000000`

Will python interpreter optimize the op like `a[:10]=[1,2,3]` to `O(1)` time ?
Is there any difference between `a[:10]=[1,2,3]` and `a[:3]=[1,2,3]`? I mean difference between whether length changes.

Comment: Hi! Have you tried `a[:10] = [1, 2, 3]` in your Python interpreter?

Comment: @Jondiedoop I've tried and find no noticable difference of time when a is a 10**7-long list

Answer (score 3):

There's very *much* a difference between the two statements:

```
a[:10] = [1,2,3]
a[:3]  = [1,2,3]
```

The first involves actual *deletion* of some elements in the list, whereas the second can just change the elements that are already there. You can verify this by executing:

```
print(len(a))
```

before and after the operation.

There's a [useful web page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) that shows the various operations on standard Python data structures along with their time complexities. Deleting from a list (which is really an array under the covers) is `O(n)` as it involves moving all elements beyond the deletion area to fill in the gap that would otherwise be left.

---

And, in fact, if you look at the [`list_ass_slice`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1fb72d2ad243c965d4432b4e93884064001a2607/Objects/listobject.c#L574) code responsible for list slice assignment, you'll see it has a number of `memcpy` and `memmove` operations for modifying the list, for example:

```
if (d < 0) { /* Delete -d items */
    Py_ssize_t tail;
    tail = (Py_SIZE(a) - ihigh) * sizeof(PyObject *);
    memmove(&item[ihigh+d], &item[ihigh], tail);
    if (list_resize(a, Py_SIZE(a) + d) < 0) {
        memmove(&item[ihigh], &item[ihigh+d], tail);
        memcpy(&item[ilow], recycle, s);
        goto Error;
    }
    item = a->ob_item;
}
```

Basically, the code first works out the size difference between the slice being copied and the slice it's replacing: `d = n - norig`. Before copying the individual elements, it inserts some new elements if `d > 0`, deletes some if `d < 0`, and does neither if `d == 0`.

Comment: Thanks!  in the web pape I think 'set slice' is the operation I ask. Even thougth it show time complexity O(k+n) ,but interpreter will find there is no need to move the other elements when the replaced section remain the same length?Am I right?

Comment: Where you replace the slice with an equal number of new elements, so there might be no need for shifting at all, reducing the complexity to `O(k)` you expected where k is the length of the slice.

Comment: @ARAT: That is correct. The code works out the size difference between the slice being copied and the slice it's replacing. Before copying elements, it inserts some new elements if the difference is positive, deletes some if it's negative, and does neither otherwise. Added to answer.